# Fine Uploader S3: Refused to get unsafe header "ETag"

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm trying to upload to S3 with the jQuery fineuploader (v 3.9.1) and have enabled debugging. All of the parts of the upload succeed but then I get an error "Problem asking Amazon to combine the parts!"

I've enabled debug on the console and get the errors [Refused to get unsafe header "ETag"] as well as this from Amazon:

> Received response status 400 with body:
>   `InvalidPart`One or more of the specified
>   parts could not be found.  The part may not have been uploaded, or the
>   specified entity tag may not match the part's entity
>   tag.eTvPFvkXEm07T17tvZvFacR4vn95EUTqXyoPvlLh1a6AADlc94v7H9.a2jcmow1pjfN1xcdw_xMx60APpXn6rGwhHYtzE0NT90Bs0IVqrkaFHW75yRl5E4nfO3Od6rWZnull0CD2DC02D0870E61R4Kpfe66IDvL44Jx9Aoicxgh9Frqd4qr8ILWHbu5YhlqGomxIBOZvfkgy4R4VsYS1

Answer (score 13):

It seems your Amazon S3 CORS XML configuration file is incorrect. Make sure you add `<ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>` to the `<CORSRule>` section as detailed below,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

More information in the [documentation on Amazon S3 servers](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html) and the [official blog post on the same thing](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/).